# Linux autostart with script in /etc/init.d/

Tags: linux, autostart, init.d

I have some trouble with starting my written C++ application each time my raspberry pi with raspbian OS boots. I found the following instructions:

http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html

So I followed all of the mentioned steps:

1. Created my script in /etc/init.d/myScript (by copying and modifying an existing one)
2. Entered the path to my C++-Programm:

> case "$1" in
> start)
>
> echo "Starting my programm..."
>
> /home/pi/myProgram
> ;;

Note: In reality this file is well formatted and I dont get a parsing error! However if I want to start my own service with

```
sudo service myScript start
```

i get the following message:

```
/home/pi/myProgram    no such process
```

Seems to me that my C++ program can not be found? What should I do?

Comment: What happens when you try to run `/home/pi/myProgram` directly from the command line?

Comment: The program starts as expected. I checked the path twice and will to this now a third time

Comment: The "service" command is a shell script, so here's a good way to get debug output: "sudo sh -x /usr/sbin/service myScript start"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"no such process" is almost certainly the output of the "killall" command, which would be invoked when you call "service myScript stop".  I think you should double-check the init script that you copied and altered; it looks like the syntax for the case...esac got mangled.

Comment: Totally stupid mistake: I mixed up the command for stop and start within the skript...